# When min date is set to today, Date field is showing an error "Please enter a value greater than or equal to NaN." on Magento

Tags: javascript, magento2

I am using Magento v2.4.0.

In certain forms, there's a date field with a minimum value set to today using JavaScript. However, when the minimum value is set to today, the form shows an error saying 'Please enter a value greater than or equal to NaN.' I've checked my code but couldn't find any errors. Any ideas on how to fix this?

HTML

```
<div class="bookTime__inputs--date">
    <label for="date">Date<sup>*</sup></label>
    <input type="date" name="appointment_date" placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY" data-validate="{'required-entry': true, 'validate-date': {dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD'}}">
</div>
```

Script

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage',
], function($) {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }

    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    jQuery('#ask_a_specialist_form input[name="appointment_date"]').attr("min", today);
});
```

[image]

I tried to change the validation ways but could not figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried using static date instead of `today`? For example `2024-02-23`

Comment: yes, already tried to add the static date but it won't work